# How to right size cloud instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, tomcat, memory, heap-memory

I have a Spring MVC web application which I want to deploy in cloud.It could be AWS, Azure, Google cloud. I have to find out how much RAM & hard disk is needed. Currently I have deployed the application at my local machine in tomcat. Now I go to localhost:8080 & click on server status button. Under OS header it tells me:

> Physical memory: 3989.36 MB Available memory: 2188.51 MB Total page
>   file: 7976.92 MB Free page file: 5233.52 MB Memory load: 45

Under JVM header it tells me:

> Free memory: 32.96 MB Total memory: 64.00 MB Max memory: 998.00 MB

[image: Server Status]

How to infer RAM & hard disk size from these data? There must be some empirical formula, like memory of OS + factor*jvm_size & I assume jvm size = memory size of applications. And while deploying to cloud we will not deploy all those example applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These stats from your local machine is in the idle state and does not have any traffic so it will definitely taking and consuming fewer resources.

You can not decide the clouds machine size on the bases of local machine memory stats but it will help little like the minimum resources can consume the application.

So the better way is to perform some load test if you are expecting the huge number of user then design accordingly on the base of load test.

The short way is to read the requirement or recommended system of a deployed application.

**Memory**

> 256 MB of RAM minimum, 512 MB or more is recommended. Each user
>   session requires approximately 5 MB of memory.

**Hard Disk Space**

> About 100 MB free storage space for the installed product (this does
>   not include WebLogic Server or Apache Tomcat storage space). Refer to
>   the database installation instructions for recommendations on database
>   storage allocation.

you can further look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13169_01/ales/docs22/installadmin/prepare.html) and [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html)

so if you want desing for staging or development then you can choose one of these two AWS instancs.

**t2.micro**

1VCPU       1GB RAM

**t2.small**

1vCPU       2GB RAM

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: "5 MB per user session", very useful information. Database will not be installed in the same EC2 - so we need not take into account database storage space.How much storage Tomcat needs? service.bat file shipped with tomcat tells me at max 256MB.

Comment: Storage is mentioned, for database better to use RDS